# What is good workout attire for weight lifting?

Tags: weightlifting, workout

I want to know what the best practices are for workout attire, what kind of clothes should one use? Loose fitting clothing, moisture wicking etc?

I'm not asking for discussion but what is commonly accepted by most trainers.

Comment: For what workout specifically?

Comment: general long workouts (weight lifting)

Comment: @Justin Have a look at some of the questions about [shoes and weightligting](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=shoes+weightlifting).

Comment: I'm asking for everything lol, not just shoes. But definitely going to read it! Any idea on how to keep one's junk from moving around without putting pressure on one's waist - using performance shorts.

Answer (score 3):

clean, simple and comfortable.  Don't wear anything that is to tight to restrict movement or to loose that may get in the way. Many weightlifters use Converse Chucks (canvas and a strip of rubber for the sole) and would probably prefer being barefoot.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to go is to wear whatever feels comfortable.

But these are what I generally see at the gym:

Upper: t-shirts or tank tops

Lower: shorts

Moisture wicking gear is a big plus especially if you sweat a lot, but not a requirement.

Shoes: comfortable sneakers.

Comment: Odd question, but is lose fitting better than tight fitting?

Comment: Whatever makes you feel comfortable.

Comment: Good answer. I would add: Wear white socks, not the argyles you wear under your slacks.

Answer (score 0):

i Think loose fitting is better than tight fitting as body get pumped up and bulged up after doing workouts and if u wear tight fitting then it will cause you uncomfortable. so prefer go with loose fitting

Comment: Your muscles don't get "pumped up" after your workout. They get bigger during recovery.

Comment: Ron, can't bodybuilding workouts engorge the muscles with blood and produce a temporary (if small) enlargement of muscles? I was under the impression that this was common practice immediately prior to bodybuilding competition, for instance.

Comment: Yes it would temporarily engorge the muscles, but not enough to tighten up your shirt to make it uncomfortable. I'm not a bodybuilder expert, but if I remember right, they try to lose their body fat % prior to their competitions while minimizing muscle loss. Usually to about 5% or less.

Comment: I thought it was beneficial to have form-fitting clothes so your form and technique can more readily be checked for correctness?